# Implement a fixed SearchBar and TableView in a Custom UIViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, uisearchbar

The purpose is to implement a fixed search bar just like Contacts in iOS7.

I have a view controller called SearchViewController inherited from UIViewController.

And I add a searchBar and a tableView as its navigationController.view's subView.

But since searchBar and tableView are separated, when I start to search, no dim effect on tableView and result table view is shown in correctly.

I just want it behaves just like Contacts app.

Here is my code:

**SearchViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class UWTabBarController;
@class InfoSessionModel;

@interface SearchViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate>
```

**SearchViewController.m**

```
#import "SearchViewController.h"
@interface SearchViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UISearchBar *searchBar;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UISearchDisplayController *searchController;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableView *tableView;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *data;

@end

@implementation SearchViewController 

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // initiate search bar
    NSInteger statusBarHeight = 20;
    NSInteger navigationBarHeight = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;

    _searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,  statusBarHeight + navigationBarHeight, 320, 44)];
//    _searchBar.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    _searchBar.delegate = self;
    _searchBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
    //NSMutableArray *scopeTitles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Employer", @"Program", @"Note", nil];
    _searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Employer", @"Program", @"Note", nil];//[@"Employer|Program|Note" componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"];


    // initiate search bar controller
    _searchController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:_searchBar contentsController:self];
    _searchController.delegate = self;
    _searchController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
    _searchController.searchResultsDelegate = self;

    // initiate table view
    _tableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, statusBarHeight + navigationBarHeight, 320, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - statusBarHeight - navigationBarHeight)];
    [_tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(_searchBar.frame.size.height, 0, _tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height, 0)];
    _tableView.delegate = self;
    _tableView.dataSource = self;

    [_tableView registerClass:[InfoSessionCell class]  forCellReuseIdentifier:@"InfoSessionCell"];
    [_tableView registerClass:[LoadingCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"LoadingCell"];

    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:_tableView];
    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:_searchBar];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (_searchController.searchResultsTableView == tableView) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return [data count];
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (_searchController.searchResultsTableView == tableView) {
        static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"LoadingCell";
        LoadingCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[LoadingCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        }

        cell.loadingLabel.text =  @"Test cell for search result";
        return cell;
    }
    else {
            //... configure cell and return cell
            return cell;
        }
    }
}

#pragma mark - UISearchDisplayController Delegate Methods
// hasn't been implemented

#pragma mark - UISearchBar Delegate Methods
- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    //move the search bar up to the correct location
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.3
                     animations:^{
                         searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(searchBar.frame.origin.x,
                                                      20,// status bar's height
                                                      searchBar.frame.size.width,
                                                      searchBar.frame.size.height);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         //whatever else you may need to do
                     }];
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)searchBarShouldEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    //move the search bar down to the correct location
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.25
                     animations:^{
                         NSInteger statusBarHeight = 20;
                         NSInteger navigationBarHeight = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;
                         searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(_searchBar.frame.origin.x,
                                                      statusBarHeight + navigationBarHeight,
                                                      _searchBar.frame.size.width,
                                                      _searchBar.frame.size.height);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         //whatever else you may need to do
                     }];
    return YES;
}
```

This is the effects of my code:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, my problem is caused by my misunderstanding of views and navigationController's views.

In view did load method:
before is:

```
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:_tableView];
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:_searchBar];
```

but should be:

```
[self.view addSubview:_tableView];
[self.view addSubview:_searchBar];
```

In this way, the original table view and result table view will show correctly.

And other things are moving search bar up and down, these things should be done through UISearchBar delegate protocol methods and UISearchDisplayController delegate protocol methods.

This is a right way to implement a **fixed searchBar and tableView bellow it**.